# Repeating text on the textbox, but just only shows once

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I was trying to show texts 50 times on the textbox, but it just show only once.
(which is the last time(50th) text)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3tpu.jpg)

'''

```
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int counting = 0;

        for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for(y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                counting++;
                richTextBox1.Text = "TEST" + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + "\r\n";
            }
        }

        textBox1.Text = counting.ToString();
```

'''

The 'counting' works great, but "TEST" is just shows one time.
What should I have to do if I can make 50 texts?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to append new text at each loop then you need to _append_ Now you are replacing the existing text with a new text for that loop. See the += string operator or the AppendText method

Comment: A text box has a multiline option which must be set to see multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a value to the text box 50 times, not building up the value as you set it.  If you want to show all 50 values, you'll need to concatenate them:

````cs
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int counting = 0;

# Start with an empty text box
richTextBox1.Text = "";

for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        counting++;
        richTextBox1.Text += "TEST" + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
}

textBox1.Text = counting.ToString();```
````

Comment: Thank you Anon! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Change the line

```
richTextBox1.Text = "TEST" + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

to 1 of 2 things:

```
richTextBox1.Text += "TEST" + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

Or

```
richTextBox1.Text =richTextBox1.Text + "TEST" + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

That Will append the new text to the existing.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. ' += ' is the key!